# How is database design done in Joomla?

Tags: database, database-design, joomla, joomla3.0

In phpMyAdmin, the tables do not show any relationships and they cannot be implemented in MyISAM tables. That means all the database relationships and data integrity need to be taken care of in the code level rather than at the database level? Is there any advantage or disadvantage of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the lack of relationships is probably a legacy from the early days of mysql. I have seen that the latest versions of Joomla is using InnoDB - tables instead of MyIsam, and this might indicate that they are thinking of adding relationships? (Innodb supports foreign keys and triggers, while myisam does not).

Obviously, it is much easier to maintain data integrity by using relationships and triggers, that doing everything at the application level. The only disadvantage I can think of is that it might require a bit more work with the coding to make sure the application don't give errors when you try to delete items with foreign keys ...

regards Jonas